# Codenameone: Screen(form) load issue

Tags: codenameone

I want to load screen dynamically reflected with changes that I made dynamically through program.

Currently when I load screen(form) it first shows  screen which i designed with GUI builder. then after that changed screen appears. I have written my code in protected void beforeHome(Form f) {}

Can you please let me know how to resolve it. My application needs to be supported on all platforms (Android, iOS, Windows) and I don't want to write native code for all platforms separately.

Comment: can you provide us with more information, e.g more source and pictures what exactly your problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `reloadForm()` method which will cause the before* method to run again.

Comment: protected void beforeHome(Form f) { findTxtName.setText(" shekhar");} here i did set name on text field dynamically. when this form(screen) open it just show textfield name which i did set on gui builder at the time of designing after that it show my dynamically set value on textfield.so i just want to start or display this form(screen) with dynamically set value not by default screen(form) which i designed with gui builder

Comment: Is this only on iOS devices for the first screen in the application?

Comment: No. its for all devices

Comment: Based on your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893690/keyboard-not-showing-when-textfield-is-focused-in-codenameone-for-ios you are clearly doing something seriously problematic in your app. I suggest including code in your questions